# Background images don't show. Rails 4, nginx, puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, nginx, assets, puma

I'm setting up rails(4.0.0) app with puma and nginx folowing this instruction http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-setup-rails-app-with-puma-and-nginx/ . But all background images and some js don't work.

my_app.conf

```
upstream my_app {
  server unix:///var/run/my_app.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name my_app_url.com; # change to match your URL
  root /var/www/my_app/public; # I assume your app is located at that location

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://my_app; # match the name of upstream directive which is defined above
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

  location ~* ^/assets/ {
    # Per RFC2616 - 1 year maximum expiry
    expires 1y;
    add_header Cache-Control public;

    # Some browsers still send conditional-GET requests if there's a
    # Last-Modified header or an ETag header even if they haven't
    # reached the expiry date sent in the Expires header.
    add_header Last-Modified "";
    add_header ETag "";
    break;
  }
}
```

production.rb

```
     config.eager_load = true

  config.assets.precompile += Ckeditor.assets

  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  config.serve_static_assets = false

  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier

  config.assets.compile = true

  config.assets.digest = true

  config.assets.version = '1.0'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  config.log_level = :info

  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)


  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # config.autoflush_log = false

  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
```

Comment: the environment is production

Comment: I think this question may be related to the other one you asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388189/background-images-in-rails-production-dont-work. Did my answer over there fix this one?

Answer (score 1):

Use try_files to check for static files before sending the request to Rails

```
location / {
index index.html
try_files $uri $uri/ @ruby;
}

location @ruby {
  proxy_pass http://my_app; # match the name of upstream directive which is defined above
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: Already tried - doesn't work. I don't think it's the case since part of assets(css, java, images) work, only background images do not(404 error)

Comment: hrm, what version of rails?

Comment: rails 4. 

UPD added production.rb